# can not delete realm file because TYPED_REALM and DYNAMIC_REALM

Tags: android, realm

I had created multiple `realm instances` with specific `configurations`, then I try to `close` all `realm instances` to delete `realm` `file` but not to success.
When I try to get some information with `RealmUtil.dumpRealmCount()` I got below message.

> total: 5 instance(s).
>   /data/data/com.myapp/files/4d461e38a17a0e229119efe458fd8e07740d639d.realm(TYPED_REALM)
>   has 3 instance(s).
>   /data/data/com.myapp/files/4d461e38a17a0e229119efe458fd8e07740d639d.realm(DYNAMIC_REALM)
>   has 0 instance(s).
>   /data/data/com.myapp/files/83e21b4390a1bedd5ca3ea95e5f1edd8d831e0b5.realm(TYPED_REALM)
>   has 2 instance(s).
>   /data/data/com.myapp/files/83e21b4390a1bedd5ca3ea95e5f1edd8d831e0b5.realm(DYNAMIC_REALM)
>   has 0 instance(s).

I can see that I have not closed some `TYPED_REALM` `instances` yet. But I don't know what's it and how to close it.

Any one can help to explain about `typed_realm` and `dynamic_realm` in this case and give me a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: A typed Realm is created using `Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config)`, a dynamic Realm by doing `DynamicRealm realm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(config)`. I don't know if that helps?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried to set a `configuration` as default and then use `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` to init realm instance.
I had tried to close all instances and use `executeTransaction()` to process data. And I still don't know why there are some `un-close instances` :(

Comment: Each time you call `getDefaultInstace/getInstance()` it has to be matched by a `close()`

Comment: But I dont need to call `close()` when `executeTransaction()`, right ?

Comment: No that should be fine. Note also that if you are using RxJava, then active subscriptions will also hold a Realm instance

Comment: Well, you have to close all of your Realm instances that you open with `Realm.getDefaultInstance()`. ALL of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are two typical patterns.

```
// activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
   super.onCreate(bundle);
   realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   if(realm != null) {
       realm.close();
   }
   super.onDestroy();
}
```

or

```
// fragment
@Override
public View onCreateView(...) {
   realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
   // ...
   return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
   super.onDestroyView();
   if(realm != null) {
       realm.close();
   }
}
```

---

Or on background threads:

```
Realm realm = null;
try {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.executeTransaction(...);
} finally {
    if(realm != null) {
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

or on API 19+ (or using Retrolambda):

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
    realm.executeTransaction(...);
}
```